# How to correctly implement UISlider in the AudioPlayerViewController for changing value of progress?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, uislider

This is the AudioPlayerViewController and it has a UISlider for changing the progress of the playing audio. I remember that this worked before. Now it throws an error that the sender is unrecognized. I recently upgraded to a new MacBook Pro M1, and newer Xcode accordingly, may it be a reason? Friends appreciate any comment, any hint, any help.

[image: This is the appearance of the AudioPlayerViewController]
[image: This is the screenShot of the error]

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import MediaPlayer
import AVKit

class AudioPlayerViewController: UIViewController {
                
    public var position: Int = 0
    public var paragraphs: [Audio] = []
    public var mainImage = UIImage(named: "placeHolderImage")
   
@IBOutlet var holder: UIView!
var player: AVPlayer?
    var playerItem: AVPlayerItem?
    var isSeekInProgress = false
    var chaseTime = CMTime.zero
    fileprivate let seekDuration: Float64 = 15
    var playerCurrentItemStatus: AVPlayerItem.Status = .unknown

                // User Interface elements
private let albumImageView: UIImageView = {
let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
    imageView.layer.shadowRadius = 3
    imageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 6, height: 6)
    imageView.layer.shadowRadius = 8
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
return imageView
}()
    
private let paragraphNumberLabel: UILabel = {
let label = UILabel()
label.textAlignment = .left
label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .light)
label.numberOfLines = 0 // allow line wrap
label.textColor = UIColor(named: "PlayerColors")
return label
}()
                
private let albumNameLabel: UILabel = {
let label = UILabel()
label.textAlignment = .left
label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: .bold)
label.numberOfLines = 0 // allow line wrap
label.textColor = UIColor(named: "PlayerColors")
return label
}()
                
private let songNameLabel: UILabel = {
let label = UILabel()
label.textAlignment = .left
    label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .ultraLight)
label.numberOfLines = 0 // allow line wrap
label.textColor = UIColor(named: "PlayerColors")
return label
}()
    
private let elapsedTimeLabel: UILabel = {
let label = UILabel()
label.textAlignment = .left
label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .light)
label.textColor = UIColor(named: "PlayerColors")
label.text = "00:00"
label.numberOfLines = 0
return label
}()
        
private let remainingTimeLabel: UILabel = {
let label = UILabel()
label.textAlignment = .left
label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .light)
label.textColor = UIColor(named: "PlayerColors")
label.text = "00:00"
label.numberOfLines = 0
return label
}()
        
private let playbackSlider: UISlider = {
    
let v = UISlider()
v.addTarget(AudioPlayerViewController.self, action: #selector(progressScrubbed(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
v.minimumTrackTintColor = UIColor.lightGray
v.maximumTrackTintColor = UIColor.darkGray
v.thumbTintColor = UIColor(named: "PlayerColors")
v.minimumValue = 0
v.isContinuous = false
return v
}()
   
    
    

let playPauseButton = UIButton()
    
    
                

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
                    
    let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panGesture(gesture:)))
    self.playbackSlider.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
                    

let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)
            }
                catch{
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
                
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        

        
        
                
        if holder.subviews.count == 0 {
    configure()
    }
}
                func configure() {
                    // set up player
                    let song = paragraphs[position]
                    
                    let url = URL(string: song.trackURL)
                    let playerItem: AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)
                    do {
                        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setMode(.default)
                        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
                        guard url != nil else {
                            print("urls string is nil")
                            return
                        }
   
                        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
                        
                        
                        let duration : CMTime = playerItem.asset.duration
                        
                        let seconds : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
                        
                        remainingTimeLabel.text = self.stringFromTimeInterval(interval: seconds)
                        
                        let currentDuration : CMTime = playerItem.currentTime()
                        
                        let currentSeconds : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(currentDuration)
                        
                        elapsedTimeLabel.text = self.stringFromTimeInterval(interval: currentSeconds)

                        playbackSlider.maximumValue = Float(seconds)
                       
                        
                        player!.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, preferredTimescale: 1), queue: DispatchQueue.main) { (CMTime) -> Void in
                            
                            if self.player!.currentItem?.status == .readyToPlay {
                                let time : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player!.currentTime());
                                self.playbackSlider.value = Float(time)
                                
                                self.elapsedTimeLabel.text = self.stringFromTimeInterval(interval: time)
                            }
                            
                            let playbackLikelyToKeepUp = self.player?.currentItem?.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp
                            if playbackLikelyToKeepUp == false{
                                print("IsBuffering")
                                self.playPauseButton.isHidden = true
                               
                            } else {
                                // stop the activity indicator
                                print("Buffering completed")
                                
                                self.playPauseButton.isHidden = false
                                
                            }
                        }
                        
                        
                        playbackSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(AudioPlayerViewController.progressScrubbed(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
                        self.view.addSubview(playbackSlider)
                        //subroutine used to keep track of current location of time in audio file
                        guard let player = player else {
                            print("player is nil")
                            return
                        }
                        player.play()
                        
                    }
                    catch {
                        print("error accured")
                    }
                    // set up user interface elements
                    
                    //album cover
albumImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 20,
                              y: 20,
                              width: holder.frame.size.width - 40,
                              height: holder.frame.size.width - 40)
                    
                    albumImageView.image = mainImage
                    

                    
                    
                    holder.addSubview(albumImageView)
                    
                    //Labels Song name, album, artist
                    albumNameLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 20,
                                                 y: holder.frame.size.height - 300,
                                                  width: holder.frame.size.width - 40,
                                                  height: 20)
                    paragraphNumberLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 20,
                                                  y: holder.frame.size.height - 280,
                                                  width: holder.frame.size.width-40,
                                                  height: 20)
                    songNameLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 20,
                                                  y: holder.frame.size.height - 260,
                                                  width: holder.frame.size.width-40,
                                                  height: 20)
                    playbackSlider.frame = CGRect(x: 20,
                                                  y: holder.frame.size.height - 235,
                                                  width: holder.frame.size.width-40,
                                                  height: 40)
                    elapsedTimeLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 25,
                                                    y: holder.frame.size.height - 200,
                                                    width: holder.frame.size.width-40,
                                                    height: 15)
                    remainingTimeLabel.frame = CGRect(x: holder.frame.size.width-60,
                                                      y: holder.frame.size.height - 200,
                                                      width: holder.frame.size.width-20,
                                                      height: 15)
                    songNameLabel.text = song.name
                    albumNameLabel.text = song.albumName
                    paragraphNumberLabel.text = song.paragraphNumber
                    holder.addSubview(songNameLabel)
                    holder.addSubview(albumNameLabel)
                    holder.addSubview(paragraphNumberLabel)
                    holder.addSubview(elapsedTimeLabel)
                    holder.addSubview(remainingTimeLabel)
                    //Player controls
                    let nextButton = UIButton()
                    let backButton = UIButton()
                    let seekForwardButton = UIButton()
                    let seekBackwardButton = UIButton()
                    //frames of buttons
                    playPauseButton.frame = CGRect(x: (holder.frame.size.width - 40) / 2.0,
                                                   y: holder.frame.size.height - 172.5,
                                                   width: 40,
                                                   height: 40)
                    
                    nextButton.frame = CGRect(x: holder.frame.size.width - 70,
                                                   y: holder.frame.size.height - 162.5,
                                                   width: 30,
                                                   height: 20)
                    
                    backButton.frame = CGRect(x: 70 - 30,
                                            y: holder.frame.size.height - 162.5,
                                            width: 30,
                                            height: 20)
                    seekForwardButton.frame = CGRect(x: holder.frame.size.width - 140,
                                                     y: holder.frame.size.height - 167.5,
                                            width: 30,
                                            height: 30)
                    seekBackwardButton.frame = CGRect(x: 110,
                                            y: holder.frame.size.height - 167.5,
                                            width: 30,
                                            height: 30)
                    let volumeView = MPVolumeView(frame: CGRect(x: 20,
                                                                y: holder.frame.size.height - 80,
                                                                width: holder.frame.size.width-40,
                                                                height: 30))
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    holder.addSubview(volumeView)
                    //actions of buttons
                    playPauseButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapPlayPauseButton), for: .touchUpInside)
                    backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapBackButton), for: .touchUpInside)
                    nextButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapNextButton), for: .touchUpInside)
                    seekForwardButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(seekForwardButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
                    seekBackwardButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(seekBackwardButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
                    //styling of buttons
                    playPauseButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(systemName: "pause.fill"), for: .normal)
                    nextButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(systemName: "forward.fill"), for: .normal)
                    backButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(systemName: "backward.fill"), for: .normal)
                    seekForwardButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(systemName: "goforward.15"), for: .normal)
                    seekBackwardButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(systemName: "gobackward.15"), for: .normal)
   
                    playPauseButton.tintColor = UIColor(named: "PlayerColors")
                    nextButton.tintColor = UIColor(named: "PlayerColors")
                    backButton.tintColor = UIColor(named: "PlayerColors")
                    seekForwardButton.tintColor = UIColor(named: "PlayerColors")
                    seekBackwardButton.tintColor = UIColor(named: "PlayerColors")
                    
                    holder.addSubview(playPauseButton)
                    holder.addSubview(nextButton)
                    holder.addSubview(backButton)
                    holder.addSubview(seekForwardButton)
                    holder.addSubview(seekBackwardButton)
                    
                    
}
    
    
    
    @objc func progressScrubbed(_ playbackSlider:UISlider)
        {
            
            let seconds : Int64 = Int64(playbackSlider.value)
        let targetTime:CMTime = CMTimeMake(value: seconds, timescale: 1)
        
            
            player!.seek(to: targetTime)
            
            if player!.rate == 0
            {
                player?.play()
            }
        }
    
    
    
    @objc func panGesture(gesture:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let currentPoint = gesture.location(in: playbackSlider)
        let percentage = currentPoint.x/playbackSlider.bounds.size.width;
        let delta = Float(percentage) * (playbackSlider.maximumValue - playbackSlider.minimumValue)
        let value = playbackSlider.minimumValue + delta
        playbackSlider.setValue(value, animated: true)


    }
    
    func setupNowPlaying() {
      // Define Now Playing Info
      var nowPlayingInfo = [String : Any]()
      nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] = "Unstoppable"
      
      if let image = UIImage(named: "placeHolderImage") {
        nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork] = MPMediaItemArtwork(boundsSize: image.size) { size in
          return image
        }
      }
        nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime] = player?.currentTime
        nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration] = playerItem?.duration
        nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate] = player?.rate
      
      MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = nowPlayingInfo
    }
    
    func updateNowPlaying(isPause: Bool) {
      var nowPlayingInfo = MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo!
        nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime] = player?.currentTime
      nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate] = isPause ? 0 : 1
      
        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = nowPlayingInfo
    }
    
    func setupNotifications() {
      let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
      notificationCenter.addObserver(self,
                                     selector: #selector(handleInterruption),
                                     name: AVAudioSession.interruptionNotification,
                                     object: nil)
      notificationCenter.addObserver(self,
                                     selector: #selector(handleRouteChange),
                                     name: AVAudioSession.routeChangeNotification,
                                     object: nil)
    }

    @objc func handleRouteChange(notification: Notification) {
      guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
        let reasonValue = userInfo[AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey] as? UInt,
        let reason = AVAudioSession.RouteChangeReason(rawValue:reasonValue) else {
          return
      }
      switch reason {
      case .newDeviceAvailable:
        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        for output in session.currentRoute.outputs where output.portType == AVAudioSession.Port.headphones {
          print("headphones connected")
          DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            player?.play()
          }
          break
        }
      case .oldDeviceUnavailable:
        if let previousRoute =
          userInfo[AVAudioSessionRouteChangePreviousRouteKey] as? AVAudioSessionRouteDescription {
          for output in previousRoute.outputs where output.portType == AVAudioSession.Port.headphones {
            print("headphones disconnected")
            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                player?.pause()
            }
            break
          }
        }
      default: ()
      }
    }
    
    @objc func handleInterruption(notification: Notification) {
      guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
        let typeValue = userInfo[AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] as? UInt,
        let type = AVAudioSession.InterruptionType(rawValue: typeValue) else {
          return
      }
      
      if type == .began {
        print("Interruption began")
        // Interruption began, take appropriate actions
      }
      else if type == .ended {
        if let optionsValue = userInfo[AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionKey] as? UInt {
          let options = AVAudioSession.InterruptionOptions(rawValue: optionsValue)
          if options.contains(.shouldResume) {
            // Interruption Ended - playback should resume
            print("Interruption Ended - playback should resume")
            player?.play()
          } else {
            // Interruption Ended - playback should NOT resume
            print("Interruption Ended - playback should NOT resume")
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
    @objc func didTapPlayPauseButton() {
        if player?.timeControlStatus == .playing {
                           //pause
                           player?.pause()
                           
                           
                           //show play button
                           playPauseButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(systemName: "play.fill"), for: .normal)
                           //shrink image
                           UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                               self.albumImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 50,
                                                             y: 50,
                                                             width: self.holder.frame.size.width - 100,
                                                             height: self.holder.frame.size.width - 100)
                               
                           })
                           
                       } else {
                           //play
                           player?.play()
                           //show pause button
                           playPauseButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(systemName: "pause.fill"), for: .normal)
                           
                           //increase image size
                           UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
                               self.albumImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 20,
                                                             y: 20,
                                                             width: self.holder.frame.size.width - 40,
                                                             height: self.holder.frame.size.width - 40)
                               
        })
    }
}

    private func setupView() {
        setupConstraints()
    }
    
    private func setupConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            holder.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            holder.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            holder.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            holder.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
        ])
    }

    func stringFromTimeInterval(interval: TimeInterval) -> String {
        
        let interval = Int(interval)
        let seconds = interval % 60
        let minutes = (interval / 60) % 60
        let timeFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        timeFormatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 2
        timeFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
        timeFormatter.roundingMode = .down
        
        guard let minsString = timeFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: minutes)),
              let secStr = timeFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: seconds)) else {
            return "00:00"
        }
        return "\(minsString):\(secStr)"
    }

    @objc func didTapBackButton() {
                       if position > 0 {
                           position = position - 1
                           player?.pause()
                           for subview in holder.subviews {
                               subview.removeFromSuperview()
                           }
                           configure()
                       }
                   }
                   
    @objc func didTapNextButton() {
        if position < (paragraphs.count - 1) {
    position = position + 1
    player?.pause()
    for subview in holder.subviews {
    subview.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    configure()
    }
                       
}
    
    @objc func seekBackwardButtonTapped(){
        
        if player == nil { return }
        
            let playerCurrentTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(player!.currentTime())
        var newTime = playerCurrentTime - seekDuration
            
        if newTime < 0 { newTime = 0 }
        player?.pause()
        let selectedTime: CMTime = CMTimeMake(value: Int64(newTime * 1000 as Float64), timescale: 1000)
            
        player?.seek(to: selectedTime)
            player?.play()
        }
    
    @objc func seekForwardButtonTapped(){
        
        if player == nil { return }
        if let duration = player!.currentItem?.duration {
            let playerCurrentTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(player!.currentTime())
            let newTime = playerCurrentTime + seekDuration
            
            if newTime < CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
            {
                let selectedTime: CMTime = CMTimeMake(value: Int64(newTime * 1000 as Float64), timescale: 1000)
                player!.seek(to: selectedTime)
            }
            player?.pause()
            player?.play()
        }
    }
    
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        player?.play()
        UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
    }
        
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        player?.pause()
        UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = false
        
    }

    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBOutlet weak var lblCurrentTime: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var sliderPlayback: UISlider!

var timeObserverToken: Any?
var player : AVPlayer?
   

func addPeriodicTimeObserver() {
        
        let timeScale = CMTimeScale(NSEC_PER_SEC)
        let time = CMTime(seconds: 0.05, preferredTimescale: timeScale)

        timeObserverToken = self.player?.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: time,
                                                          queue: .main) {
            [weak self] time in
            
            self?.sliderPlayback.setValue(Float(time.seconds), animated: true)
            self?.lblCurrentTime.text = transToHourMinSecForCurrentPlayerTime(time: Float(time.seconds))
                     
        }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).